# How to go from Blob to ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, blob, arraybuffer

I was studying Blobs, and I noticed that when you have an ArrayBuffer, you can easily convert this to a Blob as follows:

```
var dataView = new DataView(arrayBuffer);
var blob = new Blob([dataView], { type: mimeString });
```

The question I have now is, is it possible to go from a Blob to an ArrayBuffer?

Comment: Blobs aren't in native JS format. They're like references to data but not the actual data. Data from a `Blob` cannot be directly read but it could be done with some APIs.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) API consumes a (immutable) [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/) from which the data can be retrieved in several ways. The *OP* only asked for `ArrayBuffer`, and here's a demonstration of it.

```js
var blob = GetABlobSomehow();

// NOTE: you will need to wrap this up in a async block first.
/* Use the await keyword to wait for the Promise to resolve */
await new Response(blob).arrayBuffer();   //=> <ArrayBuffer>
```

alternatively you could use this:

```
new Response(blob).arrayBuffer()
.then(/* <function> */);
```

---

> **Note:** This *API* isn't compatible with older (*ancient*) browsers so take a look to the [**Browser Compatibility Table**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Browser_compatibility) to be on the safe side ;)

Comment: Clever trick and not to be confused with `Blob.arrayBuffer()` which actually has quite poor compatibility even in 2020, https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_blob_arraybuffer or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer

Comment: What's the performance of this? Does it copy the data in the Blob or just return a view of it?

Comment: @GaryO Haven't benchmarked it, I assume it copies the blob and returns a view over it.

Comment: Sigh, it appears it does copy. That's bad if the blob is big!

Comment: FYI `await blob.arrayBuffer()` has good support now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 162):

You can use `FileReader` to read the `Blob` as an `ArrayBuffer`.

Here's a short example:

```js
var arrayBuffer;
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function(event) {
    arrayBuffer = event.target.result;
};
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

Here's a longer example:

```js
// ArrayBuffer -> Blob
var uint8Array  = new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3]);
var arrayBuffer = uint8Array.buffer;
var blob        = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);

// Blob -> ArrayBuffer
var uint8ArrayNew  = null;
var arrayBufferNew = null;
var fileReader     = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload  = function(event) {
    arrayBufferNew = event.target.result;
    uint8ArrayNew  = new Uint8Array(arrayBufferNew);

    // warn if read values are not the same as the original values
    // arrayEqual from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-javascript-array-equals
    function arrayEqual(a, b) { return !(a<b || b<a); };
    if (arrayBufferNew.byteLength !== arrayBuffer.byteLength) // should be 3
        console.warn("ArrayBuffer byteLength does not match");
    if (arrayEqual(uint8ArrayNew, uint8Array) !== true) // should be [1,2,3]
        console.warn("Uint8Array does not match");
};
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
fileReader.result; // also accessible this way once the blob has been read
```

This was tested out in the console of Chrome 27—69, Firefox 20—60, and Safari 6—11.

Here's also a live demonstration which you can play with: https://jsfiddle.net/potatosalad/FbaM6/

**Update 2018-06-23:** Thanks to Klaus Klein for the tip about `event.target.result` versus `this.result`

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsArrayBuffer()
- https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-readAsArrayBuffer

Comment: doesn't this seem like a lot of code.. for something that should be simple?

Comment: @HenleyChiu I edited the answer to include a short version of the code.  The longer example is intended to be fully self-contained (shows how to create the ArrayBuffer, the Blob, and back again).  I haven't been able to find a synchronous way to read a Blob without using a [Web Worker](http://dev.w3.org/html5/workers/) and [FileReaderSync](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReaderSync).

Comment: Some people really want to prove the callback hell exists. It makes sense for LARGE blobs, but for normal use cases JavaScript should provide a sync method.

Comment: FYI `await blob.arrayBuffer()` has good support now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 22):

Or you can use the fetch API

```
fetch(URL.createObjectURL(myBlob)).then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
```

I don't know what the performance difference is, and this will show up on your network tab in DevTools as well.

Comment: Or just `new Response(blob).arrayBuffer()`

Comment: Or `await blob.arrayBuffer()` which now has good support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 18):

Just to complement Mr @potatosalad answer.

You don't actually need to access the function **scope** to get the result on the **onload** callback, you can freely do the following on the **event** parameter:

```
var arrayBuffer;
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function(event) {
    arrayBuffer = event.target.result;
};
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

Why this is better? Because then we may use arrow function without losing the context

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = (event) => {
    this.externalScopeVariable = event.target.result;
};
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

Answer (score 12):

There is [now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer#Browser_compatibility) (Chrome 76+ & FF 69+) a [Blob.prototype.arrayBuffer()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) method which will return a Promise resolving with an ArrayBuffer representing the Blob's data.

```js
(async () => {
  const blob = new Blob(['hello']);
  const buf = await blob.arrayBuffer();
  console.log( buf.byteLength ); // 5
})();
```

Comment: Unfortunately currently does not work in Safari (yet)

Comment: @HerrZatacke, see my answer

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer#browser_compatibility Safari supports this API with version 14+.

Answer (score 12):

This is an async method which first checks for the availability of `arrayBuffer` method. This function is backward compatible and future proof.

```
async function blobToArrayBuffer(blob) {
    if ('arrayBuffer' in blob) return await blob.arrayBuffer();
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror = () => reject();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    });
}
```

Comment: It seems to be a wrong answer since the return value of `reader.onerror` cannot be a function. so it should be like the following. `reader.onerror = (e) => reject(e)` or `reader.onerror = reject`

Comment: I had to move readAsArrayBuffer before the onload/onerror declarations for my unit tests to run.

Answer (score 10):

`await blob.arrayBuffer()` is good.

The problem is when iOS / Safari support is needed.. for that  one would need [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/aZgaz8vm):

```
Blob.prototype.arrayBuffer ??=function(){ return new Response(this).arrayBuffer() }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51758200/3702797 and all the other fallbacks are already there.

Comment: @Kaiido, See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341912/how-to-go-from-blob-to-arraybuffer/63568311#comment109377805_60202012. My method is superior and is required until iOS support. (after which the line can simply be removed)

Comment: And a FileReader is still needed in IE. My point is that your answer doesn't offer anything more than what the previous answers gave. If one wants to build a polyfill, all the various ways of doing the same task are already there.

Comment: @Kaiido, IE requirements are rare. ¶ Yep, this is the only answer with the polyfill.