# JS + HTML5: Uploading an audio blob via HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

I was wondering if I can create a HTML file input of an audio blob using javascript/jQuery.  I'm audio recording online and want to POST the recording along with other HTML form inputs once the user presses form submit.

Edit:
Elaborating, I have an audio blob stored in session cache.  I also have a HTML form with text and file inputs that already hold values.  I want to bind or incorporate the blob into the form so it will be POSTed when the HTML form is submitted.

I could create a formdata from the existing HTML form and append the blob as a key/value, but this seems "dirty."  I'm going with this for now, but it would be great if someone knows how to incorporate/bind a cached blob with an existing HTML form.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: What is an audio blob?!

Comment: binary large object of an audio file - [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)

Comment: you can send it has a byte array

Comment: Could you give me an example?  I know it's possible to send the blob directly via a formdata but I would like to append it to a current form.

Comment: I've been working on this.  You'd suggested something I hadn't tried so I wanted to understand what you meant by "you can send it has a byte array."

Answer (score 2):

all you have to do is convert you blob to an ArrayBuffer and post that, you can see how to convert the blob here:

[How to go from Blob to ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341912/javascript-how-to-go-from-blob-to-arraybuffer)

Note: You could also post it as a blob, but then your server would need to know how to handle it.

As far as sending the blob or ArrayBuffer, see this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

Cheers, hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @joseeight thanks for the suggestion!  I actually can handle the file, but I have a simpler question.  Aside from the audio blob, I have a form of texts and files that are completely separate from the blob.  I want to add the audio blob in cache (that was live recorded on the clientside) to the existing form of text and file inputs.  I tried using js/jquery but I already know one can't set file input values.  So, I was wondering if I had another option aside from rewriting my form to submit an ajax formdata request.  By the way, the site is built on django.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you can use Form Data to rebuild your form and append the file, see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did, but I wanted to avoid that.  Oh well.  Thanks!

Comment: I see, sorry, I don't think there's a simpler way than that :)

Comment: Fair enough.  I was stupid and had created an entirely different flow that has too many moving parts/dynamic inputs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method to upload a blob (additionally, this uses ajaxForm and iframe set to true for reasons I won't go into but perhaps relevant to your situation).

```
        if (audioRecBlob) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event){
                $('#audioData').remove();
                var audioData = $('<input type="hidden" id="audioData" name="audioData">');
                audioData.val( event.target.result );
                $('#yourForm').append( audioData );

                realSubmit();
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(audioRecBlob);
        } else {
            realSubmit();
        }
```