# Use .svg that is served using the wrong Content-Type

Tags: html, mime-types, content-type

Is there a way to use an `.svg` as an `<img>` or a `CSS` `background-image` that is served using the wrong Content-Type, i.e. not `image/svg+xml`?

**Runtime used:** Electron (Chromium)

**`Content-Type` served:** `text/binary`

Comment: I guess that depends a lot on the browser, have you tried? What content type is being served?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115581/can-i-explicitly-specify-a-mime-type-in-an-img-tag

Comment: @Pekka웃 updated question

Comment: Simplest idea that comes to mind is having a proxy that fetches the resource and passes it on with the correct content type, but that may not be feasible in your situation. Another, to fetch the resource and pass it to the `<img>` tag as a base64 encoded inline string (but don't know how that works within Electron and how strict the security model is). Who is doing the serving in your case?

Comment: @Pekka웃 our own servers so should be fixed but it will take some time. I use webpack anyway and can bundle the `.svg` to an inline data-URI, just wondering if there is a solution for HTML