# How to convert Blob to Int16Array

Tags: javascript, mp3

I have a WAV file in Blob and in order to convert it to MP3 I need to convert it to Int16Array first (to follow the example from here: https://github.com/zhuker/lamejs).

E.g.

```
var mp3encoder = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(2, 44100, 128);
// instead of `var samples = new Int16Array(44100);` I want something like `var samples = new Int16Array(blob);`
var mp3Tmp = mp3encoder.encodeBuffer(samples);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You have to employ the FileReader API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341912/how-to-go-from-blob-to-arraybuffer

Comment: Did you manage to sort this out?

Answer (score 3):

Provided you know the data is actually a blob of 16-bit `int`s, then yes, it's possible:

1. Read the `Blob` into an `ArrayBuffer` via its [`arrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) method *(the original answer had to use `FileReader`, but now `Blob` has an `arrayBuffer` method; see the edit history if for some reason you have to support old environments without it)*:

   ```
   samples.arrayBuffer()
   .then(buffer => {
       // ...
   })
   .catch(error => {
       // ...handle/report error...
   });
   ```
2. View the `ArrayBuffer` as an `Int16Array` via the [`Int16Array` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int16Array/Int16Array):

   ```
   const data = new Int16Array(buffer);
   ```

Now `data` is the array buffer from the blob viewed as an `Int16Array`.

Something along these lines:

```
samples.arrayBuffer()
.then(buffer => {
    const data = new Int16Array(buffer);
    // ...use `data` here...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error...
});
```

Comment: Now I can upvote :)
Note you can also use the onload event argument `.target.result`

Comment: Didn't work for me:

Sometimes getting this error, sometimes it saves just "pssh" as mp3
Uncaught RangeError: byte length of Int16Array should be a multiple of 2

Comment: @DmitryMind - That error means that you don't have a blob containing 16-bit int values. If you did, its length would be a multiple of 2. From the first sentence of the answer: *"Provided you know the data is actually a blob of 16-bit ints..."*

Comment: I'm getting blob from microphone via mediaRecorder, how can I control these values?

Comment: @DmitryMind - I don't know, I haven't used it. But I wouldn't expect it to return 16-bit int values, looking at [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API) it seems more likely to be bytes. So you'd want a `Uint8Array` or an `Int8Array` instead of an `Int16Array` (if I'm correct about that).