# Explicitly casting Any/Blob to ArrayBuffer still gives me a Blob I can't process

Tags: javascript, dom, casting, scala.js

Over my websocket I expect a Binary message from the server to the client (the other way works). I want to cast that to an `Array[Byte]` to further process it it as protobuf-message

```
ws.onmessage = {
  (event: MessageEvent) =>
    val msg = event.data.toString
    dom.window.console.log(msg) 

    val x = event.data.asInstanceOf[ArrayBuffer]
    val df = new DataView(x)
    dom.window.console.log("result")
    dom.window.console.log(bin2User(df).toString)
}

private def bin2User(data: DataView): User = {
    val bytes = new Array[Byte](data.byteLength)

    for(index <- 0 to data.byteLength) {
      bytes(index) = data.getInt8(index)
    }

    User.parseFrom(bytes)
  }
```

now `dom.window.console.log(msg)`  gives me

> [object Blob]
>
> Blob { size: 9, type: "" }

I would expect the `x` be of type `ArrayBuffer` because of the **explicit** cast, but alas, it's not, as I get

> TypeError: DataView: expected ArrayBuffer, got Blob

How can I overcome this?

I tried with:

```
val fr = new FileReader
fr.readAsArrayBuffer(event.data.asInstanceOf[Blob])
val y = fr.result.asInstanceOf[ArrayBuffer]
dom.window.console.log(y)
```

but this prints `null` for `y` and also

> TypeError: y is not an object

Comment: Hmm.  I haven't worked with `Blob`, so I'm not sure of the answer, but I think your experiment at the end should be on the right track.  `asInstanceOf` can't work -- that only says to the compiler, "I know what type this value *already* is, so ignore what you know and believe me".  It doesn't do conversions.  From what I see elsewhere on SO, I would have expected the `FileReader` approach to work. You may want to put JavaScript / DOM tags on this question -- it probably isn't a Scala.js question per se...

Comment: `FileReader` `.result` is returned asynchronously. Have you tried using `load` event handler of `FileReader` to check `.result`? Have you set `.binaryType` of `WebSocket` to `ArrayBuffer`?

Comment: Note that in Scala.js `asInstanceOf[T]` where `T` is a subtype of `js.Any` **does not do anything** (not even any checking).

Comment: I don't know anything about scala.js, but in general you want to set the `binaryType` property to `"arraybuffer"` to receive a ArrayBuffer instead of a Blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there: `FileReader` is asynchronous so you'll have to:

```
val fr = new FileReader
fr.onload = { _ =>
  val y = fr.result
  dom.window.console.log(y)
}

fr.readAsArrayBuffer(event.data.asInstanceOf[Blob])
```

This is essentially a translated example from [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341912/how-to-go-from-blob-to-arraybuffer).

You'll probably want to wrap this in a future API:

```
import scala.concurrent.Promise

def blob2ArrayBuffer(blob: Blob): Future[ArrayBuffer] = {
  val result = Promise[ArrayBuffer]()
  val fr = new FileReader
  fr.onload = { _ => result.success(fr.result) }
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(blob)
  result.future
}
```

Comment: Which imports do you use for your method? `Promise` of Scala.js does not work for me, neither does the one from Scala

Comment: Ah, I need to expect the `fr.result.asInstanceOf[Blob]`

Comment: Actually, shouldn't the `Promise[Blob]` be a `Promise[ArrayBuffer]` ;o) ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Also added the import.

Answer (score 1):

As some people already pointed out, setting `ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer"` is enough too.

Doing it like this:

```
 ws.onmessage =
      {
        ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer"

        (event: MessageEvent) => 

            val msg = event.data.asInstanceOf[ArrayBuffer]
            dom.window.console.log(msg)
```

results in

> ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 9 }

Comment: You probably want to move the assignment to `ws.binaryType` above `ws.onmessage = `.

Comment: @gzm0, nope, did not intend to. It's only important it's before the event. I can send as blob or string and expect as arraybuffer that way.

Comment: Moving `ws.binaryType =` upwards does the exact same thing in terms of execution order (have a look at the generated JavaScript code if you don't believe it). However, it is much less confusing if the order in the code is the same as the execution order.

Comment: But I only want this to be interpreted as arraybuffer in case of `ws.onmessage` hence I put it in this block, because that's what blocks are for (maybe I get you wrong though)