# Converting from blob to pdf

Tags: javascript, html, blob

I'am able to convert my pdf files into blob. But what i want to do is the opposite by converting it from blob to pdf.

Here is my code converting it from pdf to blob. I just need some advice where i can return from blob to pdf.

```
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET","./template.pdf");
xhr.responseType="arraybuffer";

xhr.onload = function (e){
    var blob = new Blob([xhr.response]);
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

    console.log(url);

    var embed=document.getElementById("template");
    embed.src = url;
}

xhr.send();
```

The result will return a blob from console=> blob:http://localhost:8081/d42939da-e318-4d88-b46f-8240efaa7b1c and once i paste this on the url, it will show me a huge blob text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go from Blob to ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341912/how-to-go-from-blob-to-arraybuffer)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the content type when creating the blob to tell it is a pdf.

```
var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
```