# How to get byte array from a file in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html

I've got a form for uploading Avatar image and I have to send the image file in the format of binary string; so far I've tried `ReadAsBinaryString` from `FileReader` but it's not working:(
here's my code:

```
<form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
      <div className="row justify-content-center mb-2">
           <input type="file" id="avatar"  accept="image/png, image/jpeg" 
            onChange={this.uploadedImage} />
           <button type="submit" className="btn btn-sm btn-info">Send</button>
       </div>
  </form>
```

and that is how I'm trying to use `ReadAsBinaryString` in `uploadedImage` function:

```
uploadedImage(e) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    console.log(file); //I can see the file's info
    reader.onload= () => {
        var array = new Uint32Array(file);
        console.log("_+_array:",array); // the array is empty!
        var binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null,array) ;
        console.log("__binaryString:",binaryString);
      this.setState({
        file: binaryString
      },()=>{
        console.log(this.state.file);//ergo file is set to an empty image
    });
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
}
```

so to sum it up, I get a file but I can't convert it to byte array; Is there anything wrong with this code or this approach is completely wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you wanting to display the avatar image without uploading it to a server?

Comment: this is wrong `var array = new Uint32Array(file);` you are using `file` info variable to read the data, instead you **should use the `data` passed to handler**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go from Blob to ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341912/how-to-go-from-blob-to-arraybuffer)

Comment: @DacreDenny I'm trying to get the image and then send it as a byte array to the server, U see the byte array is part of a data that I have to send to the backend API, I mean due to back-end restrictions, I have to convert the file to byte array and that is a must

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This approach worked for me:

```
function readFileDataAsBase64(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (event) => {
            resolve(event.target.result);
        };

        reader.onerror = (err) => {
            reject(err);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}
```

You can call `reader.readAsBinaryString()` if you wish to use binary string. More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: How to check Return response and file date after convert to binary ?

Comment: with .then((res)=>console.log("result", res)); you can see results on the console and save them to a variable then you can change that.
---->  

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (event) => {
            resolve(event.target.result);
        };

        reader.onerror = (err) => {
            reject(err);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });.then((res)=>console.log("resdfsdfs",res));

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read the file data using the `file` variable which contains the file info **not the file contents**. Try sth like the following:

[FileReader documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

```
uploadedImage(e) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    console.log(file); //I can see the file's info
    reader.onload= () => {
        var array = new Uint32Array(reader.result); // read the actual file contents
        console.log("_+_array:",array); // the array is empty!
        var binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null,array) ;
        console.log("__binaryString:",binaryString);
      this.setState({
        file: binaryString
      },()=>{
        console.log(this.state.file);//ergo file is set to an empty image
    });
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to *tomericco*'s answer, here is one with few more lines to get the actual final byte array :

```
 const test_function = async () => {

      ... ... ...

      const get_file_array = (file) => {
          return new Promise((acc, err) => {
              const reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = (event) => { acc(event.target.result) };
              reader.onerror = (err)  => { err(err) };
              reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
          });
       }
       const temp = await get_file_array(files[0])
       console.log('here we finally ve the file as a ArrayBuffer : ',temp);
       const fileb = new Uint8Array(fileb)

       ... ... ...

  }
```

where `file` is directly the `File` object u want to read , this has to be done in a `async` function...

Answer (score 0):

```
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    // we need to get the raw bytes
    const buffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
    // each entry of array should contain 8 bits
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
```