# How to read a Audio file as binary string in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to read a file input as a binary string. Therefore I have written a binary string reader (following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56001073/how-to-get-byte-array-from-a-file-in-reactjs)), but I get the error message:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute
>   'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type
>   'Blob'.

**Reader:**

```
ReadAudioasBinaryString(e) {
    const audio = e.target.files[0];

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (event) => {
            resolve(event.target.result);
        };

        reader.onerror = (err) => {
            reject(err);
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(audio);
    }, console.log (audio));
}
```

**Input**

```
<div className="form-group">
         <label>Audio</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="file"
              name="audio"
              onChange={this.ReadAudioasBinaryString}
              ref={this.inputRef} //
           />
</div>
```

Happy for every hint!

Comment: I guess you want `const audio = e.target.files[0];` or something like that? And if that works, your resolving result is currently discarded. What is the end goal? What's supposed to happen with the audio file selected by the user?

Comment: Exactly. The goal is that the user inserts a file, this file should be read as a binary string. Because the backend needs files as binary string. So somehow I have to convert the file into a binary format.  This is what this function `ReadAudioasBinaryString` is supposed to do. See also this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56001073/how-to-get-byte-array-from-a-file-in-reactjs)

Comment: Ok, so did you try the change I suggested (which is what it says in the accepted answer btw, not sure why you changed it to `.name`?) Anyway, you can ditch the Promise wrapper, just use `this.setState({ binaryString: event.target.result })` in the `onload`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Yes i changed the code as you suggested to `const audio = e.target.files[0];` (see also the updated post). Unfortently The error messages stays the same.

Comment: Here's example code that'll display the binary string: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-worker-w3fwb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi @ChrisG it works thank you! if you post it as a post i could might accpet it as an answer. Anyway many thanks, it helped me a lot!