# How to Convert File Image to Byte[] ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, asp.net-core-webapi, binaryfiles

I want to send image to api end point and end point accept byte[] how can i handle this.
My code is:
ReactJS function on upload button click:

```
    let onClickHandler = () => {
        let data = new FormData()
        data.append('file', image);

        axios.post("/Contact/ContactForm/",  {
            
            AttachedImage: data

        }, {
            
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                }
            // receive two parameter endpoint url ,form data
        })
            .then(res => { // then print response status
                console.log('binary Response......',res.statusText)
            });
}
```

and my endpoint controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ContactForm([FromBody] Contact model)
        {
            try
            {
                model.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
                await _contact.ContactForm(model);
                return Ok("Submitted Successfully");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { return this.BadRequest("Not Submitted Successfully" + ex.ToString()); }
        }
```

and finally Model.cs Class

```
public byte[] AttachedImage { set; get; }
```

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56001073/how-to-get-byte-array-from-a-file-in-reactjs help you?

Comment: @BlackSheep no it is not helping me.

Comment: You can try to change the method in the post, it may be instructive for you：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363419/how-to-get-binary-string-from-arraybuffer/16365505#16365505

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> want to send image to api end point and end point accept byte[] how can i handle this.

Please note that [the default model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#no-source-for-a-model-property) can not handle byte array that would be set to `null`.

To upload image file and bind the data to a byte array property of your model class, you can try following solutions:

**Solution 1** - convert the selected image file to base64 encoded string, and use a [`ByteArrayModelBinder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#working-with-the-bytearraymodelbinder) to convert it into a byte array.

```
public class Contact
{
    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(ByteArrayModelBinder))]
    public byte[] AttachedImage { set; get; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { set; get; }

    //...
    //other properties
    //...
 }
```

Testing Data

```
{
    "attachedImage": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMsAAA.....",
    "creationDate": "2021-08-21T15:12:05"
}
```

Testing Result

[image]

**Solution 2** - implement and use a custom model binder like below to bind selected image file to byte array.

```
public class ImageToByteArrayModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        // ...
        // implement it based on your actual requirement
        // code logic here
        // ...



        if (bindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files["AttachedImage"]?.Length > 0)
        {
            var fileBytes = new byte[bindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files["AttachedImage"].Length];

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files["AttachedImage"].CopyTo(ms);
                fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(fileBytes);
        }



        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Testing Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks For your Solution.
Solution 1 is working for me.
By the way, in client-side, we can convert image to byte by:
const img = btoa(image);

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know if the API will accept it, but you can convert the file to a [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) which is an array with all bytes of the file represented as Integers.

```
let file: File = ...
let uint8 = new Uint8Array(await file.arrayBuffer())
```

Comment: hi, it is not working. On my receiving end   "byte[] AttachedImage" is used to store the image.  I need to convert the image in a way that is byte[] AttachedImage accepted.