# How to extract blob data from websocket response

Tags: javascript, api, websocket, blob, extract

I'm trying to get market data from bingx websocket API but once my connection stablished i recieve blob data and i dont know how can i read candlestick data from that blob response with javascript does any one know how can i extract data?

here is my Js code :

```
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://open-ws-swap.bingbon.pro/ws');

    ws.onopen = (event) => {
        const msg = {
            id: "548",
            reqType:"sub",
            dataType: "market.kline.BTC-USDT.1min",
        }
        ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
        console.log('connection stablished!')
    }


    // Listen for messages
    ws.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log(event.data);
    }

    ws.onclose = function(event) {
        console.log(event)
    };

    ws.onerror = function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    };
```

And here is the result in console:

[image]

I tried this answer bot not working:
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195675/deserialize-data-from-websocket-response)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs ->

> All response data from Websocket server are compressed into GZIP
> format. Clients have to decompress them for further use

So using this information we can use `DecompressionStream` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DecompressionStream  to uncompress the data, and then use `TextDecoder` to convert that into to text, finally `JSON.parse` to convert into an object.

Finally you will want to watch for the `Ping` message, as the API will disconnect if you don't send a `Pong`.

eg.

```js
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://open-ws-swap.bingbon.pro/ws');


async function decompressBlob(blob) {
  const ds = new DecompressionStream("gzip");
  const decompressedStream = blob.stream().pipeThrough(ds);
  return await new Response(decompressedStream).blob();
}




ws.onopen = (event) => {
   const msg = {
      id: "548",
      reqType:"sub",
      dataType: "market.kline.BTC-USDT.1min",
   }
   ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
   console.log('connection stablished!')
}

// Listen for messages
ws.onmessage = async function(event) {
   const data = await decompressBlob(event.data);
   const txt = new TextDecoder().decode(await data.arrayBuffer());
   if (txt === 'Ping') {
     //this keeps the api open
     ws.send('Pong');
   } else {
     console.log(JSON.parse(txt));
   }
}

ws.onclose = function(event) {
   console.log(event)
};

ws.onerror = function(error) {
   console.log(error);
};
```